# How to publish +Inf and -Inf in sensor_msgs/Range?

Tags: ros, arduino, range, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the documentation, if value of sonar is more than max range, +Inf should be published. Similarly for min range and -Inf. But how do I do that? The script would only accept float values.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356616/how-to-publish-+inf-and--inf-in-sensor_msgs/range?/) by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on ROS Answers with karma: 463 on 2020-07-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`float("inf")` and `float("-inf")` for python.

`std::numeric_limits<sensor_msgs::Range::_range_type>::infinity()` for C++. `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()` will also work, but assumes that range will not change to float64 in the future.

On Arduino you can use `INFINITY`.

---

Originally posted by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) with karma: 249 on 2020-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2